# Shouldn't this function be not invertible?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Given question:

> Define a function f : $\ D \to \mathbb{Z}$ by $\ f(x) = x^2 + 5 $, where $\ D = \{-4, -3, -2, -1, 0\} $.
>
> Find $\ f^{-1} $.

My answer is that there isn't an inverse of function f because f is not bijective, as per I was taught and stated in my lecture notes. While f is one-to-one (injective), f is not onto (surjective) since set D only has 5 elements and the co-domain is the set of integers - not every element in the co-domain has a preimage.

However, the model answer given is such:

> $\ y = x^2 + 5 \to x^2 = y - 5 \to x = \sqrt{y - 5} $
>
> $\ f^{-1}(x) = -\sqrt{x-5} $

I have tried searching on this and everywhere seems to say the same thing E.g. [link1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2730961/the-difference-between-inverse-function-and-a-function-that-is-invertible), [link2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1215365/are-all-functions-that-have-an-inverse-bijective-functions), [link3](http://math.colorado.edu/%7Ekstange/has-inverse-is-bijective.pdf) - that for a function to be invertible, it must be bijective.

I am rather confused at the moment... am I wrong and the model answer is correct?

Thanks!

Comment: The way the question is stated you are right. If the question said find $f^{-1}:f(D) \to D$ then the given answer would have been right.

Comment: Many times questions like this one are meant to be understood as: show $\;f\;$ is one-to-one and find its image $\;E\;$, and then $\;f:D\to F(D)=E\;$ is bijective and etc. It is not the most precise way to ask but sometimes it is what it must be understood. Check the source of the question.

Comment: The question does not mention inverse or invertibility. It asks about $f^{-1}$. That is well-defined even for functions that are neither injective nor surjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are **technically** right. The function `f` is not invertible because it is not surjective.

However, f is invertible when limiting the co-domain to the range `f(D)` of the function. In that case, the function is the inverse.

> $\ f^{-1}(x) = -\sqrt{x-5} $

---

Perhaps a even nicer way of writing that would be:

> $\ g : \{ x \in \mathbb{Z} , x \geq 5\} \to D$
>
> $\ g(x) = -\sqrt{x-5}$

Hence:

> $f(D) = \{5, 6, 9, 14, 21, 30\}$
>
> $\ g|_{f(D)} = f^{-1}$

---

**Perhaps the biggest question is how you should answer this question in the first place**.

Sure, being technically correct is important for math, but perhaps seeing "the big picture" that there is a condition for a inverse function when limiting its domain to specific subset is just as important. Figuring out the overall intent of the questions can be a very useful skill when trying to prove a statement.

If this is a "homework/exam question" though, keep in mind that this "see the big picture" and "common sense" is subjective - from my experience, different fields and mathematicians have different expectations and it is often worth to talk with your instructor to see how things align.

For instance, if I was working with someone that pointed that the function was not invertible because of the domain I would say something like "Sure, you are right, but you understood what I meant." in the sense of "Hey, this is probably just a detail in the whole scheme of what we are doing".

Answer (score 0):

Note that the range of $f$ is $f(D) = \{5, 6, 9, 14, 21, 30\}$

\begin{align}
   \ y &= x^2 + 5 \\
   x^2 &= y-5 &\text{Note that $y-5 \ge 0$.} \\
   x &= -\sqrt{y-5}
\end{align}