# T is an open map if and only if $T^{-1}$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis

Let X and Y topological space and $T:X\rightarrow Y$ invertible. Prove that $T^{-1}$ is continuous if and only if T is an open map.

Is T bijective?

$\Leftarrow)$ if $T$ is an open map then $\forall A \subseteq X$, $A$ open set then  $T(A) \subseteq Y$ is an open set. $T$ is an invertible map so $(T^{-1}(T(A))=A$ i.e. the preimage of an open set of $Y$ is an open set on X and this is the definition of continuity for $T^{-1}$?

$\Rightarrow)$: $T^{-1}$ is continuous so the preimage of an open set in Y is an open set in X. T is invertible so T sends open set in X in open set in Y i.e. T is an open map

Comment: Which definition are you using for continuity?

Comment: T is continuous iff the preimage of an open set is an open set

Comment: Then it is pretty straightforward.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If T is open  that means it takes open sets in X to open sets in Y.  To prove $T^{-1}$ is continuous then clearly preimage of an open set in X is open in Y as $(T^{-1})^{-1}$ is nothing but T itself which is open by the hypothesis. Similarly the converse follows.

Invertible is by definition bijective.

Comment: *"Invertible is by definition bijective.*" It depends on the definition! See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2415856/43608

Comment: It's right my proof up?

Comment: T inverse is a map from Y to X @GiuliaB

Comment: I've correct the solution using the preimage. Is it right now?